# review board diff not uploading after 1st successfull upload

Tags: git, bitbucket, review-board

So here is my situation.

I have a git repo at bitbucket and I have linked it with the rbcommon account.
I clone the repo, make a change, commit and use "rbt post -g" to successfully upload the diff on rbcommons. After I get a ship-it on the review, I push the changes to repo. Then I do a git pull and repeat the same. But every such attempt fails with the following :-

```
>>> Making HTTP GET request to https://rbcommons.com/s/abc/api/review-requests/
>>> Making HTTP POST request to https://rbcommons.com/s/abc/api/review-requests/
diff_kwargs {'parent_diff': None, 'base_dir': ''}
>>> Making HTTP GET request to https://rbcommons.com/s/abc/api/review-requests/32/diffs/
>>> Making HTTP POST request to https://rbcommons.com/s/abc/api/review-requests/32/diffs/
>>> Got API Error 105 (HTTP code 400): One or more fields had errors
>>> Error data: {u'fields': {u'path': [u'error']}, u'stat': u'fail', u'err': {u'msg': u'One or more fields had errors', u'code': 105}}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/rbt", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('RBTools==0.6.2', 'console_scripts', 'rbt')()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rbtools/commands/main.py", line 134, in main
    command.run_from_argv([RB_MAIN, command_name] + args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rbtools/commands/__init__.py", line 416, in run_from_argv
    exit_code = self.main(*args) or 0
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rbtools/commands/post.py", line 801, in main
    submit_as=self.options.submit_as)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rbtools/commands/post.py", line 553, in post_request
    raise CommandError(u'\n'.join(error_msg))
rbtools.commands.CommandError: Error uploading diff
```

One or more fields had errors (HTTP 400, API Error 105)

```
path: error
```

Your review request still exists, but the diff is not attached.

https://rbcommons.com/s/abc/r/32/

I have tried it with multiple repos, the behavior is same, diff is not attached after the 1st attempt.

Any pointers ?

Comment: Have you fixed this? I'm having same issue. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I had to pull the changes as my local copy of the project was not synchronized with the remote repo.